# CA1703 CodeAnalysis Error and CasingExceptions

Tags: code-analysis

I have a text resource "{0} by Test GmbH" which is correctly spelled because GmbH is the official Abbreviation for "Gesellschaft mit beschränkter Haftung". I understand that Microsoft CodeAnalysing tries to tokenize it into "Gmb" and "H" however I think it should be possible to introduce this term as known with that specific spelling and casing with this CodeAnalysingDictionary:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Dictionary>
  <Words>
    <Unrecognized>
    </Unrecognized>
    <Recognized>
      <Word>Gmbh</Word>
    </Recognized>
    <Deprecated>
    </Deprecated>
    <DiscreteExceptions>
      <Term>GmbH</Term>
    </DiscreteExceptions>
  </Words>
  <Acronyms>
    <CasingExceptions>
      <Acronym>GmbH</Acronym>
    </CasingExceptions>
  </Acronyms>
</Dictionary>
```

However it does not work out:

```
CA1703  Resource strings should be spelled correctly    
In resource 'MyCode.Properties.Resources.resx', 
referenced by name 'CopyrightWithCompanyName', 
correct the spelling of 'Gmb' in string value '{0} by Test GmbH'.
```

How can I adjust the dictionary correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, provided that `GmbH` should be interpreted as a *compound word* that consists of the words `Gmb` and `H`, the casing of `GmbH` is correct.

So, in order for `GmbH` to be seen as valid by Code Analysis and thereby eliminate [CA1703](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264483.aspx), simply add `gmb` as a [recognized word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514188.aspx#BKMK_DictionaryWordsRecognizedWord) to your [custom dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514188.aspx) file:

```xml
<Dictionary>
  <Words>
    <Recognized>
      <Word>gmb</Word>
      <!-- ... -->
    </Recognized>
    <!-- ... -->
  </Words>
  <!-- ... -->
</Dictionary>
```

I confirmed that this works in Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514188.aspx#bkmk_dictionaryacronymscasingexceptionsacronym 
entries in the CasingExceptions are only applied to CA1709: Identifiers should be cased correctly, not to resources.

I have the exact same problem but no solution other then suppress the warning